# SOAP and Remote Services with Open Source platforms, Recommendations

Tags: web-services, open-source, soap, soa, recommendation-engine

I'm a .Net developer by trade, but have done open source development in the past for fun. I need recommendations on which open source languages work particularly better (or even better yet, stable) than others.

At home I'm developing sites on LAMP servers and prefer PHP and Python. Are either of those well suited for remote data/methods? I'm hoping there is something similar to .Net's WCF if possible.

Comment: "work particularly better (or even better yet, stable) than others."?  What does this mean?  Can you clarify?  Please define 'better' and 'stable'.

Comment: What I'm asking for is others' opinions on what they believe works well. Is Python or PHP good at building remote/web services or are they too much trouble? By stable I mean that if the language utilizes frameworks or particular 3rd party libraries, are they mature and stable?

Comment: What does `stable` mean?  Crashes rarely?  API changes rarely?  Commercial company has solid finances?  What does 'stable' mean?  What does 'better' mean in the context of this question?  If you can't define "work particularly better", then remove the words from the question.

Comment: Ok I'll try to specify in plain, plain English. When something is better than another, in this case programming languages, its Pro's (also known as benefits) outweigh the Pro's of other languages. Do you have a recommendation or just enjoy semantic processing? :)

Comment: Okay.  "benefits"?  What do you consider beneficial.  For example "open source" is NOT beneficial in some people's definition.  If you want information that's useful, you're going to have to be precise.  If you want useless opinions without supporting facts, you can continue to be breezy and informal.

Comment: You don't need to answer -- clearly -- but it's hard to guess what **you** find valuable.  I guess that "stable" means that the companies supporting the open source project have solid finances.  Is that correct?  I guess that "better" means "More use of Oracle database features".  How'd I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use .NET and WCF for your hobby projects? WCF services can be developed in express version of VS which is free.

If you want to develop services in PHP try [WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/). It is free with some advanced WS-* protocols (but still with very limited set compared to WCF or Java frameworks).

Comment: Thanks, if it weren't for my web platform of choice being LAMP when I work on home projects I would certainly use WCF instead. I like to write code at home that's different than what I write all day at work which is .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Application_Server and Java?  Since Oracle purchased Sun, they seem "stable".  Java is clearly "better" now that Oracle owns it.

Comment: I like your sarcasm. But seriously, seeing that you develop with python, what do you think about building services with Python? Is it well suited? By that, I mean are python services robust in security and application stability? In the context of hobby web development, is it _fun_ to develop Python services?

I appreciate the Java suggestion but I don't think I'd like to use Java. I would though, like to hear your opinions on developing Python services. Does Python have libs that come with the language to write them or would I need third party libs/frameworks for that?

Comment: @jlafay: Here's the problem.  Your question is vague.  This comment is less vague.  Please **update** your question to be as precise as possible.  I cannot reconcile the question overall with this comment.  Please **simplify** and **focus** so that I can figure out the things you do not know.

Comment: @jlafay: If you cannot clarify your question, then this is the **only acceptable answer**.  There's no way you can demonstrate that this answer does not satisfy your constraints.  You can focus your constraints, however,  making this answer invalid.